# How do I carry search parameter values on another page in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, search

I've got an advanced parameterized query, the user sets the parameters and accordingly the query is build. I point the action of the form to a result page and on that page I fetch values using `$_POST`.

I get these values correctly but the moment I refresh the page I lose the values of `$_POST`. Do I need to use `$_SESSION` for this? Because I don't want so many sessions, then I had to unset all once the user has used them, so how do I do it?

**Form**

```
<form action="result.php?script_id=3&sub_script_id=1">
<label for="search_for">Search For</label>
<select id="search_for" name="contact_first_name">
<?php
    while($throw_names = mysqli_fetch_array($fetch_advance_param_values)) {
?>
    <option value="<?php echo $throw_names['contact_first_name']; ?>"><?php echo $throw_names['contact_first_name']; ?></option>
<?php
    }
?>
</select>
<br />
</form>
```

**results.php**

```
<?php
$fetch_results = mysqli_query($running_db, 
"SELECT rec_num, record_locked, contact_first_name, contact_last_name,
contact_mobile_no, contact_office_no FROM tbl_contacts WHERE 
contact_first_name = '{$_POST['contact_first_name']}' 
AND group_id_entry={$_SESSION['user_group_id']} 
ORDER BY $sort_column_name $sort_order $limit_records");
?>
```

Don't worry, right now am directly using `$_POST['contact_first_name']` in my query, this is just for test purpose, later I'll use `mysqli_real_escape_string()`

Comment: Maybe not a really clean way but you could pass it in your url?

Comment: @ToonCasteele that's a very bad idea...no I cannot

Comment: is using html5 an option?

Comment: I'm just wondering why you wouldn't use sessions? or cookies for that matter. Why would you worry about adding 1 field to your session?

Comment: @ToonCasteele what if there are multiple fields?

Comment: comma or semicolon seperate them and put them in the same field? example: `"field1Name=fiel1Value;field2Name=field2Value"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get why you are concerned about using sessions or GET parameters. A search form is usually implemented with GET anyways.

But there *is* another option: save the search itself in the database (then a POST form actually makes sense):

1. search form gets submitted
2. save search query as new row in a `searches` table
3. redirect to something like `/searches/?id=1234`
4. on that page, rebuild the search query from the `searches` table and execute it

At first glance this solution looks a bit overkill but it offers new possibilities like caching a search result or offer the user to save favorite searches. So there are scenarios where this approach makes sense.

Comment: Ya I can try this, the only concern of using get is what if there are too many parameters, so I don't want to go with that approach

Answer (score 0):

In the first page where the post is sent to:

```
setcookie('searchquery','I want cookies');
```

in page 2

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['searchquery']))
    {
    $search = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_COOKIE['searchquery']);
    }
```

Comment: You saying I should store the whole query in a session or a cookie?'

Comment: Not the query, the search terms that were filled in.
Never store a query because you reveal the database setup to potential hackers